# Ext of Tate-modules of abelian varieties

Tags: abelian-varieties, galois-representations

Let $K$ be a local field (in fact, finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$) and let $A$ and $B$ be abelian varieties over $K$.

Associated to $A$ and $B$ are the Tate-modules $T_p(A)$ and $T_p(B)$.

Both of these are canonically $G_K:=\mathrm{Gal}(\bar{K}/K)$-modules (or $K[G_K]$-modules if someone prefers this).

What I want to do is compute $\mathrm{Ext}^1_{K[G_K]}(T_l(A),T_l(B))$ for all $l$, even $l=p$ (and if possible $\mathrm{Ext}^2_{K[G_K]}(T_l(A),T_l(B))$).

Are there any results out there in this direction?

If not, does anyone have a clue how to compute a projective resolution of a Tate-module (as a $K[G_K]$-module$?

Also, would it matter if I instead considered the completed group algebra $K[[G_K]]$?

**Aside** Yesterday I attended the ceremony where the named mathematician collected his Abel-price, and today, the Abel-lectures by said mathematician and Richard Taylor. Unfortunately, I realized I needed to know the answer to this question when I got back to my office, otherwise I could've pestered recipient and Taylor. :P 
But hey, now you all get to think about this instead!

Comment: Over a finite field, these Ext groups are studied in one of my 1968 Inventiones papers. The same techniques may work over local fields.

Comment: Daniel, probably you mean to write $\mathbf{Z}_ {\ell}[G_K]$ rather than $K[G_K]$. Also, the Ext's are same as (profinite) Galois cohomology of the Tate module for $B$ tensored against the linear dual of the Tate module of $A$.  This linear dual is Tate twist of Cartier dual, and Cartier dual is Tate module of dual abelian variety.  So using Tate duality would convert the Ext^2 into a concrete thing. 

Comment: @Brian, I see your point with $\mathbb{Z}_l$. I was thinking $K$ but you're right: the way I phrased the question it should be the $l$-adic integers. However, I don't understand what you are saying for the rest. Care to elaborate? Maybe as a de facto answer? 

Comment: @Jim: somewhere in the back of my mind I had a faint memory of reading something by you and Waterhouse (quite recently actually) where you refer to a paper of yours where this was proven. I haven't looked at it yet, but I will, and see if the same technique, or some version of it, goes through in the local case also. Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel: I'm just alluding to the principle whereby Hom from a "finite free" object is same as invariants in tensor product against its dual. Now pass to derived functors (first at torsion level, then pass to inverse limits) to relate an Ext to group cohomology. 

Comment: Brian, call me stupid but I don't know the principle your talking about. Maybe if you write it out in formulas I know what you're alluding to (or give a reference). Given this, I understand what you're saying next, so that's ok. Thank you for your patience! :) 

Comment: @Daniel: ${\rm{Hom}}_ {G}(M,N) = (M^{\vee} \otimes N)^G$ provided $M$ has suitable "freeness" to make sense of the right side.  Under this freeness, right side has all failure of exactness captured in the step of $G$-invariants.  So taking derived functors of both sides gives the result for torsion coefficients, then need to be careful about how things are defined with non-torsion coefficients (e.g., your Ext^2 needs to have a "continuity" condition built in). 

Comment: Brian, now it's clear what you mean! Also, I've been thinking about this today and checking up in Jim's (Milne) book (from his webpage: thank you!) "Arithmetic Duality Theorems" (2nd ed) where in chapter I.0 (specifically, pages 5-7) the result I need (at least in princple) appears in the form of a spectral sequence! I mean, I still need to compute a Galois cohomology group, but that might be easier. Thank you both!